# Is there a way to start the same Spring Batch job twice for two different input files?

Tags: performance, spring-batch, partitioning

In an effort to improve the performance of a long running batch job that processes a huge file, we would like to run the same job multiple times concurrently for different partitions of the input file (i.e. for multiple separate input files). When we do that, Spring batch complains that the same job already started and can't be started again.

I read somewhere that we can pass different jobParameters for each instance to differentiate between the job instances. We tried that but it didn't work and it's still failing with the same error. Does anyone have other ideas?

Comment: In the title of the question you say `two different input files?` but in the description you say `different partitions of the input file (i.e. for multiple separate input files)`. It is not clear if you have physical partitions (aka a huge file is split into smaller files) or logical partitions (aka the same file but different partitions based on offsets). Can you clarify this point?

Comment: It's a huge file split into smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

> It's a huge file split into smaller files.
>
> Does anyone have other ideas?

You can start a job for each partition file (with the partition file name as a job parameter). This way, you should have different job instances and your problem should be solved.